# Python auto import module, when version is python2 or python3

Tags: python

what I expect is: no matter the python version is `3.7` or `2.7`, I can use

```
import mylib
```

to import mylib

right now, I am using

```
import mylib_py3 as mylib # for python3
```

```
import mylib_py2 as mylib for python2
```

I want something like this in mylib.py:

```
import sys
PY3 = sys.version_info[0] == 3
if PY3:
   return import mylib_py3
else:
   return import mylib_py3
```

How to write mylib.py?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
import importlib

import sys
PY3 = sys.version_info[0] == 3
if PY3:
    mylib = importlib.import_module(mylib_py3)
else:
    mylib = importlib.import_module(mylib_py2)
```

Or do you need to have the string `import mylib` in your code for some reason?

Comment: It works,  so I need to use ```import mylib.mylib as mylib```

Comment: No. Just use it normal way. If you want to access classes inside it, then mylib.ClassNameInsideMylib

Comment: Can't you just do `import mylib_py3 as mylib`? (instead of `mylib = importlib.import_module(mylib_py3)`)

Comment: You are right Roy Cohen. I started as an attempt to directly get the lib and pasted that code. However that is not happening here either..

Comment: Actually, I am writing a SDK, which for developer can use only ``` import mylib ``` no matter python2 or python3.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import sys
exec("import mylib_py{} as mylib".format(sys.version_info[0]))
```